# how to add an item under a menu item android?

Tags: java, android

i have three dots icon in my app, that has items(settings,profile) now i have to create an item(delete my account) under settings this is my code

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/account_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="settings" />

    <item
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="profile" />
```

and i have tried a code

```
item
        android:id="@+id/account_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="settings" />
    <menu>
         <item
               android:id="@+id/delete_account"
               android:title="Delete My Account" />
        </menu>

        <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="profile" />
```

Comment: it shows settings item 2 times under three dots icon

Answer (score 0):

Use this..

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/delete_account" android:title="@string/delete_account"
    android:orderInCategory="101" app:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/profile" android:title="@string/profile"
    android:orderInCategory="102" app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way also :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_login"
            android:icon="@drawable/signsignout"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/login"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_legal"
            android:icon="@drawable/legal"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/legal"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_quit"
            android:icon="@drawable/quit"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/quit"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: Feel free to upvote / accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

look at this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

this will give you exact idea about how to create action bar and all related stuff.

https://www.google.com/design/icons/index.html

here you will get your icon.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

**Android doesn't support a menu under another menu**.You have to create an activity for that.
In that activity you can add functionality for logout.
Create one activity eg; LogoutActivity and go to that activity by clicking setting menu.